# HDF5 to Dask (Python) efficient way for multiple datasets to be filtered

Tags: python-3.x, bigdata, hdf5, dask, h5py

I need to load multiple hdf5 files, retrieve certain channels (if present, otherwise discard the file), filter those channels with a used-defined filter function in a lazy way: since the overall data may exceed my RAM. And finally write them back to hdf5 files. I am using h5py and dask.

I have noticed that I have to keep the file(s) open in order to perform computation on the dask array: is it so or am I doing something wrong?

I have first tried to use dask dataframes: I get the following error
raise ValueError('No objects to concatenate')

My datasets are after few levels and finally they are in a structure like

```
commonPath + '/' signalName '/MEASURED'
```

where commonPath is a fixed path (file dependent) and signalName is the signal name.

so I have tried the following

```
dd.read_hdf(file_name, key = commonPath +'/*/MEASURED')
```

and the previous error is raised. I get the same response even if I feed manually few channels or a single fixed key.

Therefore, I have tried with dask arrays. They seem to do the job, but slicing does not work if I use a dask array as logical index: it forces me to compute the array. Suppose I want the row only where a certain condition is met (e.g. >0) what is the best way of achieving this?

Finally is it better to output a hdf5 file(s) with several datasets or one data set with a bidimensional (dask) array? To do the filtering at the moment I evaluate the dask calling the compute method, then wrap it into a numpy array and finally I use logical indexing; what is the best practice?

Comment: Keep in mind that `h5py` is a `numpy` interface to `hdf5`.  So a downloaded dataset (or portion there of) will be a `ndarray`.  Similarly the writes are from arrays.  Slicing and indexing of datasets looks a lot like `numpy` indexing, but has limitations.  http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/dataset.html#fancy-indexing

Comment: Then would you suggest another package to read hdf5 files? Thanks

Comment: As far as I know those are HDF5 limitations.  Feel free to study HDF5 docs to prove me wrong.

Comment: That is why I would have liked to use dask dataframes directly, as in
dd.read_hdf(file_name, key = commonPath +'/*/MEASURED'); yet, it does not seem to be working with my datasets

Comment: According to the dask documentation (http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-creation.html) if one 1) creates a reference to a HDF5 file using h5py  with h5py.File(filename) 2) finds the pointer to the relevant dataset 3) wrap it into a dask array all computations are completely lazy "This process is entirely lazy. Neither creating the h5py object nor wrapping it with da.from_array have loaded any data."

Comment: It doesn't sound like `dask`is doing anything special.  In `hp5y` creating a link to a dataset doesn't load the data, that is, it doesn't create an array.  You have to use a slice as described in http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/dataset.html#reading-writing-data